# Vue.js 2: Cant useTwo-way Computed Property in combination with vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I cant get Two-way Computed Property in combination with vuex to work.

If there are input changes I want to set `getIsUnsavedData` to true and "copy"/commit the changes into a new variable `$store.state.authenticatedUser.changedData`. After there is any change I want the input to `get()` its value from `$store.state.authenticatedUser.changedData` instead of `$store.state.authenticatedUser.data` to display the change.

At fist everything works like expected. If there are input changes, the changed value will be replicated in the `$store.state.authenticatedUser.changedData` property. The `getIsUnsavedData` value changes to true and the get() points to the replicated data.
There is only one bug left. Suddenly the computed property never changes although the vuex store is updating correctly. The `set()` function still gets called, but the `get()` doesn't .

```
<ui-textbox @change="valueChanged" v-model="userName"></ui-textbox>
// ...
  computed: {
    userName: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getIsUnsavedData ? this.$store.state.authenticatedUser.changedData.name : this.$store.state.authenticatedUser.data.name
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('setChangedUserData', {
          key: 'name',
          value: value
        })
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    valueChanged() {
      this.$store.commit('setUnsavedState', true)
    }
  },
// ....
```

[image: Actual input value][image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mine library

https://github.com/yarsky-tgz/vuex-dot

it's done for such situations, to make code footprint of setters/getters in your code much less.

```
<template>
  <form>
    <input v-model="name"/>
    <input v-model="email"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import { takeState } from 'vuex-dot';

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...takeState('user')
        .expose(['name', 'email'])
        .dispatch('editUser')
        .map()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

(updated to reflect Andor's input)

v-model can point to a computed property but it needs to handle work a bit differently than when it just refers to data.

[vue's doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html)

applying the section on two-way computed properties:

```
<ui-textbox v-model="userName"></ui-textbox>
// ...
computed: {
  userName: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.userName
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateUserName', value)
    }
  }
}
```

I might be missing something about what you're doing but this is how I'd start to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not true that a v-model should point to data instead of a computed property. Read the part about two way computed properties here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html